# Finding the Transformation to a Canonical form for a Quadric Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am attempting to calculate the intersection of [quadric surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric) defined by $0 = X^T A X$,  $0 = X^T B X$, $0 = X^T C X$ with X = [x, y, z, 1]. Matrices A, B and C are real and symmetric.

There are several methods for solving, most of which trace to [Levin's Method](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=360355) (e.g. [Xu](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167839605000233), [Wang](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167839603000815)), or [Dupont's](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771710700123X) [rational](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717107001241) [method](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717107001253) with [implementation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772105000982).

Despite it's apparent flaws, I am interested in implementing Levin's method. I am stuck on the one of the steps in the method, where I am required to transform a "pencil" (two intersecting surfaces) into canonical form. The "pencil" is guaranteed to be a [ruled surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface) quadric under the conditions that I am interested in.

So, I need to find some matrix $P$ that transforms $Q_R: X^T R X$ (i.e. quadric of the pencil) into a canonical form.  In my specific problem, I know that my ruled surface is a [Hyperbolic Paraboloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid) based on the eigenvalues of the pencil, which has a normal form of $x^2 - y^2 + z$.

That is, find some [congruence transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) $R = P^T S P$, where R is the pencil, S is the canonical form (which I don't know what it is) and P is the transform I need to find.

This is where I'm stuck. Levin's paper instructs me to firstly calculate a rotation matrix $R_u$ from the principle submatrix of $R$ (i.e. the upper 3x3), which can be achieved via an [Eigendecomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix). Easy enough.

Next, however, I need to find a translation matrix $T = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ a & b & c & 1\end{bmatrix}$, which gets me into a canonical form, $P = T R_u$. This is done by "eliminating, by congruence transforms, as many other elements as possible". (At this point, it  references a technical report from 1976 that [I cannot find for the life of me](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&q=J.+Z.+Levin%2C+%22A+Parametric+Algorithm+for+Drawing+Pictures+of+Solid+Objects+Bounded+by+Quadric+Surfaces%2C%22+Technical+Report+CRL-46&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=)).

Hence, I would like to ask:

- What is the canonical form that I need, given that I know the shape of the resultant (a hyperbolic paraboloid)?; and
- How do I perform the necessary congruence transforms to find my desired $P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a while, but I have an answer.

This answer describes the transformation of a hyperbolic paraboloid into canonical form. The procedure is similar for other quadric shapes.

An affine transform $\mathbf{T}$ is of the form:
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
                 T_{11} & T_{12} & T_{13} & T_{14} \\
   T_{21} & T_{22} & T_{23} & T_{24} \\
   T_{31} & T_{32} & T_{33} & T_{34} \\
        0 &      0 &      0 &      1
               \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Every quadric may be transformed via affine transformations into either a diagonal matrix or a near diagonal matrix, i.e.
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{T}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{T} \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{X}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{D}$ is a (near-)diagonal matrix.  A near-diagonal matrix is symmetric and is of the form:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{D} = \begin{bmatrix}
               D_{11} &      0 &      0 & 0      \\
                    0 & D_{22} &      0 & 0      \\
                    0 &      0 &      0 & D_{43} \\
             0 &      0 & D_{43} & 0
             \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The canonical form of a hyperbolic paraboloid listed in [Xu](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167839605000233) (Table 1, pp518) is not strictly in near-diagonal form:
\begin{align}
 0 &= z - xy                               \\
   &= \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{D'} \mathbf{X}  \\
   &= \mathbf{X}^T \begin{bmatrix}
                      0 & -0.5 &   0 &   0 \\
                   -0.5 &    0 &   0 &   0 \\
        0 &    0 &   0 & 0.5 \\
        0 &    0 & 0.5 &   0
                   \end{bmatrix} \mathbf{X}
\end{align}
but may be re-written in near-diagonal form as:
\begin{align}
 0 &= -x^2 + y^2 + z                       \\
   &= \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{X}   \\
   &= \mathbf{X}^T \begin{bmatrix}
                     -1 &    0 &   0 &   0 \\
                      0 &    1 &   0 &   0 \\
        0 &    0 &   0 & 0.5 \\
        0 &    0 & 0.5 &   0
                   \end{bmatrix} \mathbf{X}
\end{align}

The Xu form $\mathbf{D'}$ and the near-diagonal form $\mathbf{D}$ are related via an affine transform:
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{D'} = \mathbf{M}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{M}
\end{align}
where:
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix}
                0.5 & -0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
                0.5 &  0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
                  0 &    0 & 1 & 0 \\
                  0 &    0 & 0 & 1 \\
              \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Since the Xu's canonical form can be found from the near-diagonal form, our immediate task is to find the transformation $\mathbf{T}$ that casts a given hyperbolic paraboloid $\mathbf{A}$ into near-diagonal form.  Although [Dupont](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771710700123X) recommends determining the transform via Gaussian Reductions to avoid radicals, perhaps the easiest first step is to remove the rotation via an Eigendecomposition as suggested by [Levin](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=360355).

Consider the principle submatrix $\mathbf{A}_u$. Since it is symmetric, of rank 2 and has known signs for the eigenvalues, an eigendecomposition may be found such that
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{A}_u = {\mathbf{R}_u}^T \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{R}_u
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{R} \in SO(3)$ and $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is in the form:
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{\Lambda} = \begin{bmatrix}
                      \lambda_+ &         0 & 0 \\
                              0 & \lambda_- & 0 \\
                              0 &         0 & 0 \\
                    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_+ > 0$ and $\lambda_- < 0$.  Therefore, the first affine transform may be built as:
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{T}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
                  \mathbf{R}_u & \mathbf{0} \\ 
                  \mathbf{0}   &          1
                \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

The second transform forces the eigenvalues to unit magnitude and it can be verified that:
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{T}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
                  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_+}} &                              0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                           0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\|\lambda_-\|}} & 0 & 0 \\
                                           0 &                              0 & 1 & 0 \\
                                           0 &                              0 & 0 & 1 \\
                \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Let $\mathbf{A}_2 = {\mathbf{T}_2}^T {\mathbf{T}_1}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{T}_1 \mathbf{T}_2$, which will be of the form:
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{A}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
                   1 &  0 & 0 & a \\
                   0 & -1 & 0 & b \\
                   0 &  0 & 0 & c \\
                   a &  b & c & d
                 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

It can be verified that the transform required to cast into near-diagonal form is:
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{T}_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
                              1 &            0 &             0 &             0 \\
                              0 &            1 &             0 &             0 \\
                   \frac{-a}{c} & \frac{-a}{b} & \frac{-1}{2c} & \frac{-d}{2c} \\
                              0 &            0 &             0 &             1
                 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Therefore, the complete transformation required to cast the hyperbolic paraboloid into Xu's canonical form is:
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{T} = \mathbf{T}_1 \mathbf{T}_2 \mathbf{T}_3 \mathbf{M}
\end{align}