# Help Understanding Levin's Pencil Method

Tags: geometry, quadrics

I'd like a little help understanding Levin's pencil method. Here is what I have gleaned so far.

Given two quadric surfaces $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{Q}'$, if an intersection exists, there is a parameterization surface $\mathbf{P}$ that is the pencil of the two quadrics that also contains the intersection.

To find this parameterization surface, one can find the roots of the equation $|\alpha \mathbf{Q} + \mathbf{Q}'| = 0$. Then, $\mathbf{P}=\alpha \mathbf{Q} + \mathbf{Q}'$

In my particular case, say that I have determined that the parameterization surface is a hyperbolic paraboloid.

This surface must be rotated to canonical form using a transformation $\mathbf{T}$ such that $uv=w$. If my parameters are $(s,t)$, then the mapping of parameters to the canonical space is $u=t,v=s,w=st$.

Once the surface is in canonical form, we can select values for the parameter $t$, and solve for $s$ using

$$\pi_2=Ct^2 +2Et + B $$
$$\rho_2 = 2[Ft^2 +(D+J)t+H]$$
$$\sigma_2 = At^2 + 2Gt + K $$
$$ \pi_2 s^2 + \rho_2 s + \sigma_2 = 0 $$

This will allow us to find the parameters $s$ and $t$, trace the curve in $uvw$ space, and then transform this curve using $\mathbf{T}^{-1}$ to bring the curve back into $xyz$ space.

~*~*~

My questions are as follows:

1. Where do the coefficients used in the equations for $\pi_2 $ , $\sigma_2 $, and $\rho_2 $ come from? Are these taken from the discriminant form of the parameterization surface $\mathbf{P}$?
2. How do I figure out the range for the parameter $t$? Is it $-\infty$ to $+\infty$? If so, presumably there is a finite interval where the intersection exists in real space?
3. To determine $\mathbf{T}$, I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146204/finding-the-transformation-to-a-canonical-form-for-a-quadric-surface) post on math.stackexchange. The initial transformation $\mathbf{T}_1$ starts with an Eigendecomposition that results in two non-zero eigenvalues and a rotation matrix in $SO3$. It's not clear to me how to find that specific Eigendecomposition...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably have already seen [this document](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00000380/document).

Comment: I hadn't seen that particular one. I had come across the Dupont paper that this one references. However I admit I am still pretty lost...